# Can't call function with variant parameter using initializer_list

Tags: c++, initializer-list, std-variant

I'm not so skilled in using std::variant and couldn't completely understand all constructor cases.

```
using map_type = std::multimap<std::string, std::string>;
using union_type = std::variant<std::string, map_type>;

void foo(union_type)
{
...
}

void foo2(map_type)
{
...
}

int main()
{
  foo({ {"key", "val"} }); // gives error "no instance of constructor"
  foo2({ {"key", "val"} }); // works fine
  foo2(map_type{ {"key", "val"} }); // works fine
}
```

As I can deduce forth [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant) is called here, but can't understand what condition is not satisfied. Could someone explain, please?

P.S. Is there some article or source to read more information and examples of using variant?

Comment: I think you are missing a pair of braces when calling `foo` - the ones for the initializer_list for the std::variant.

Comment: No, it didn't work

Comment: Most likely you did a misprint in the last function call, meaning foo(map_type{ {"key", "val"} });
If not, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template argument deduction for multimap constructor template fails because [braced-init-lists do not have a type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

You have to provide this information explicitly, creating an unnamed temporary object which in most cases will exist in compile-time only (for your code):

```
foo(map_type{ { "key", "value" } });
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that *brace-enclosed initializer lists* don't have a type, so the constructor of `union_type` fails to deduce a `T` for that case.

Nor is `foo({ std::in_place_type<map_type>, { {"key", "val"} } });` able to deduce a specialisation of `std::initialiser_list` to resolve to a that constructor.